# XML Serialization with FSharp

Tags: .net, f#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to create some XML like this:

```
<parameter name="srid" type="java.lang.Integer">24729</parameter>
```

notice that the tag is called parameter and it has two attributes, a name, and a type in addition to the actual value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
type parameter(paramName, javaType, paramValue) =
    let mutable pName = paramName
    let mutable pType = javaType
    let mutable pValue = paramValue

    public new() = 
        new parameter("","","")

    [<XmlAttributeAttribute("name")>]    
    member this.PName with get() = pName and set v = pName <- v

    [<XmlAttributeAttribute("type")>]
    member this.PType with get() = pType and set v = pType <- v
```

Maybe I'm going in the wrong direction altogether, but I'm unsure how to represent the actual value of the tag?

update: perhaps I should mention that this parameter will be one of four inside a larger "parameters" tag. Like so:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="srid" type="java.lang.Integer">24729</parameter>
    ...other parameter tags...
</parameters>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so you need

```
[<XmlText>]
```

attribute for the property that you want to serialize the value of the node

so, in your case, you would have something like

```
type parameter(paramName, javaType, paramValue) =
    let mutable pName = paramName
    let mutable pType = javaType
    let mutable pValue = paramValue

    public new() = new parameter("","","")

    [<XmlAttributeAttribute("name")>]    
    member this.PName with get() = pName and set v = pName <- v

    [<XmlAttributeAttribute("type")>]
    member this.PType with get() = pType and set v = pType <- v

    [<XmlText>]
    member this.PValue with get() = pValue and set v = pValue <- v
```

Comment: very helpful, thanks Alex. I have another question in case you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937811/how-to-xml-serialize-array-of-an-array-in-fsharp